# Change Joomla Authentification for login

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, password-hash

I'm searching in Joomla CMS for the file which is responsible for the verification of the password when login to the admin backend. I would like to change the password encryption to match with my actual mysql user databank.

It should be existing a file which says verify(input, hash) or kind of that.
I already found the encryption files under librairies.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: That's not the way Joomla works.  What do you mean by 'my actual user databack" are you saying you want to bypass the Joomla user system?  To do that you will want to create a plugin that uses your authentication rather than Joomla's. There are various ways to do that depending how you want it to work, but you will want to consider the impact that has on other parts of the system that use the user data.

Comment: You will probably be better off asking on the [joomla.se] stack exchange site.

Comment: Found a solution

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and select it or else delete your question.

Comment: @Yann Please take the time to follow Elin's good advice.  Abandoned pages represent an information deadend.  You can help others and potentially earn more points/privileges to become a more effective member of StackOverflow if you perform the simple task of explaining your solution.  Please do your part so that everyone wins.

Comment: Add in the file /librairies/src/User/UserHelper.php in the Method verifypassword your needed authentification